# Pandas group by a column and convert other columns to key:value pair

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

My Original data format

[image]

I would like to convert it to:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
output = df.groupby("id").apply(lambda x: x.to_json(orient="records")[1:-1])
>>> output
id
1    {"id":1,"topic":1,"test1":"abc","test2":null,...
2    {"id":2,"topic":3,"test1":null,"test2":null,...
```

Comment: How about converting it to a list? [{"id":1,"topic":1,"test1":"abc","test2":null,...}, {"id":1,"topic":2,"test1":"","test2":"fhg,..}]? @not_speshal

Comment: Remove the [1:-1]. Use `df.groupby("id").apply(lambda x: x.to_json(orient="records"))`